# Codeigniter - Pagination undefined function

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a function to show data from **controller** like this :

```
public function leaderboards()
    {
        if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()){
            $leaderboard = $this->FrontModel->getLeaderboard();
            $dataLeaderboard = ''; $no = 1;
            foreach ($leaderboard as $row) {
                $dataLeaderboard .='
                    <tr class="calculate-price-wrapper post">
                        <td>
                            <div class="mv-font-secondary mv-f-14"><strong>'.$no.'.</strong></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="mv-font-secondary mv-f-14"><strong>'.$row['fname'].'</strong></div>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <div class="mv-font-secondary mv-f-14"><strong>'.$this->replace_character($row['email']).'</strong></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="mv-font-secondary mv-f-14"><strong>'.$row['total_point'].'</strong></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ';

                $no++;
            }
            
            /* pagination */
            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"]     = base_url(). "leaderboards";
            $config["total_rows"]   = count($dataLeaderboard);
            $config["per_page"]     = 20;
            $config["uri_segment"]  = 3;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

            $data['dataLeaderboard'] = $dataLeaderboard($config["per_page"], $page);
            $data['pagination']     = $this->pagination->create_links();

            /* data template - header footer */
            $template['menuActive'] = 'leaderboard';
            $template['menuLoggedIn'] = $this->menuLoggedIn;

            $this->load->view('front-end/template/header', $template);
            $this->load->view('front-end/leaderboard', $data);
            $this->load->view('front-end/template/footer', $template);
        }else{
            redirect('auth', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

And here is the my **view** :

```
<!-- .main-breadcrumb-->
<section class="mv-main-body cart-main mv-bg-gray mv-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="latest-blog-title mv-title-style-3 no-text-behind" style="padding-bottom:30px;">
            <div class="title-3-text"><span class="main">LEADERBOARD</span></div>
            <div class="title-3-line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-inner">
            <div class="cart-block block-cart-table mv-bg-white mv-box-shadow-gray-1 mv-mb-50">
                <div class="mv-table-responsive">
                    <table class="mv-table-style-2">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:15%;">Pos.</th>
                                <th style="width:30%;">Name</th>
                                <th style="width:30%;">Email</th>
                                <th style="width:20%;">Point</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?=$dataLeaderboard?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div class="mv-pagination-wrapper mv-mt-25 mv-mb-25">
                        <div class="mv-pagination-style-1 has-count-post">
                            <?php echo $pagination; ?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- .mv-pagination-style-1-->
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

but it ended up having an error like this :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function <tr class="calculate-price-wrapper post"> <td> <div class="mv-font-secondary mv-f-14"><strong>1.</strong></div> </td> <td> <div class="mv-font-secondary mv-f-14"><strong>Test Name</strong></div> </td> <td > <div class="mv-font-secondary mv-f-14"><strong>te*s*n*ame*g*ai*.c*m</strong></div> </td> <td> <div class="mv-font-secondary mv-f-14"><strong>55</strong></div> </td> </tr> <tr class="calculate-price-wrapper post"> <td> <div class="mv-font-secondary mv-f-14"><strong>2.</strong></div> </td> in C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\motogp2022\application\controllers\front-end\MainController.php on line 703
```

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function
>
> 1. Test Name
>    te*s*n*ame*g*ai*.c*m  55
> 2. Filename: front-end/MainController.php
>
> Line Number: 703
>
> Backtrace:

And the line that cause the error was this line in my **controller** :

```
$data['dataLeaderboard'] = $dataLeaderboard($config["per_page"], $page); //Line 703
```

anyone know solution for this? anyhelp is really appreciated, thank you!.

Comment: where did you load the library like `$this->load->library('pagination');`?

Comment: i did that in `autoload.php`

Comment: what is this `$data['dataLeaderboard'] = $dataLeaderboard($config["per_page"], $page);`? what are you trying to do?

Comment: `$data['dataLeaderboard'] = $dataLeaderboard` as far as i know, is the same as `$data['dataLeaderboard'] = $this->FrontModel->getLeaderboard($config["per_page"], $page);`. But since i was using my controller to parse the data into my view which i use `$dataLeaderboard`, so that i can use  the `replace_character()` function for my email `$this->replace_character($row['email'])` .

Comment: Try Model code to that line

Comment: im sorry, do you mean my Model `function()`code? sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`$data['dataLeaderboard'] = $dataLeaderboard($config["per_page"], $page);`

You are using `$dataLeaderboard` as a function. You are setting it as a string of HTML, hence you're getting that the HTML does not exist as a function.

Not knowing your full code, but what I think you need to do is:

- Not create the leaderboard data as a single string, but rather as an array of HTML (so not `$dataLeaderboard .= ...` but rather `$dataLeaderboard[] = ...`.
- Then do `$data['dataLeaderboard'] = $dataLeaderboard`. For brevity, you can in your loop directly set it into an array `$data['dataLeaderboard']`. You will not set it as `$dataLeaderboard(...)`. The round bracket around the variable means you're trying to use the variable as a function, which it is not.
- For full implementation of the pagination library in CI, check this manual page: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html. There is a specific set configuration options and code lines that must be present, and your pagination library must be loaded, of course.

There might be more to do after that, but start there.

Comment: i see, and is there a way to make it remain as function?, thank you.

Comment: Well, no, it is not a function. You explicitly set it to a string of HTML code, starting at line `            foreach ($leaderboard as $row) { ... }`. I will update the answer with more info.